# Running GroupLayout replace() method on event dispatch thread causing ui hang

Tags: java, swing, awt, event-dispatch-thread, grouplayout

I have a java application that uses the groupLayout.replace() method to replace a component in a JPanel. When I attempt to perform this action on the event dispatch thread via invokeLater I occasionally get a ui hang (mainly on OS X), but when I use this method on the main thread it works fine all the time. Any help on what may be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"replace a component in a JPanel."*  I would tend to put a panel with a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) in that section of the panel.